# ASP.NET Server.Transfer() problem

Tags: asp.net, server.transfer

I am using this code...

```
Server.Transfer("/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
```

And getting the following Exception:

```
InvalidOperationException : "Failed to map the path '/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx'."
```

`StudentControlPanel.aspx` - page is located in

```
App Root -> Web -> Student
```

But my .sln file is located in

```
App Root -> Solution
```

`Default.aspx` is in

```
App Root -> Web
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Server.Transfer("~/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
```

The tilde (`~`) resolves to the root of the application.